# Updating the Sony Vaio BIOS - how do I know if I have Microsoft BitLocker?

Tags: bios, sony-vaio, bitlocker

I've got a new Sony Vaio that wants to update its BIOS; it's asking me whether I have Microsoft BitLocker. I don't think so but I want to make sure. Could Microsoft BitLocker have been pre-installed by the manufacturer or can I safely not worry about this and proceed to update the BIOS?

I think I might have chosen some encryption during setup so how can I check whether it is safe to upgrade?

It says in Control Panel "Your computer does not currently have a file encryption certificate" so I would think that I safely can proceed with the BIOS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Control Panel there's an option called BitLocker Drive Encryption, that will tell you whether or not your drive is encrypted.

More details on this can be found on Microsoft [TechNet here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-determine-if-bitlocker-drive-encryption-is-enabled.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. It says `Your computer does not currently have a file encryption certificate`so it seems I safely can proceed with the BIOS update.